# Is there any easy way to add color to single words in VB2010?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, text-rendering, text-coloring

I been trying to research it a bit and this may be frowned upon, but I don't want to learn how to do everything in VB since I'm just doing what should be a 5-10 minute program to make something a little easier for myself. So sorry for that in advance.

Anyways, I just want to add colors or any formatting really to make stuff easier to read or the like. I originally was doing textboxes with the read only attribute and found you couldn't add good formatting with it. Label was similar in terms you could add one color a label. RichTextBox was the next idea and while it works, it seems like quite a bit of work for what I'm needing.

I just want an idea on how to make a single form have a font like "these **three** *words*"

It's super easy with bbcone and html, and I can't imagine the best way in VB is something that takes around 10 lines for one string of text.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `WebBrowser` control and modify it's `DocumentText` property. That way you can write it in HTML code.

Comment: You can write a owner drawn control, where you can do EVERYTHING! By this way it is possible to use GDI+ to create the appearance and design you like for a label. But it will not be done in 10 minutes, you will need a few minutes more ..... Other idea would be to overrite the paint event in a label, and do it that way. That sould be possible within your time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Like you don't want to learn how to, but have notions of Html, then I think that the best solution for your needs is to use this 3rd party user-control, **[Html Renderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/)**, which can render html/css code.

[image]

Another approach is to use a `WebBrowser` as mentioned in the comments, however, it will be (very)slower, or also you can use the `MSHTML` ocx which Microsoft specified that is more focused to document renderization tasks, but is harder to use than the specified user-control because you will need to investigate for the online documentation and usage of the `MSHTML` members, and seems that you don't want to do, since you specified that a `RichTextBox` has too much effort for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a richtextbox1 which has some text in it - I use the code below to search through the text and change specific words to a different font/style and color :-

```
 DIM TZZ as String
 TZZ = RichTextBox1.Text
        TZZ = UCase(TZZ)


        Dim x As Single

        For X = 1 To Len(TZZ)


            Dim y As Single = InStr(TZZ, "CHANGES MADE")

            If y > 0 Then

                Dim intLength As Integer = 12
                'select the text
                RichTextBox1.Select(y - 1, intLength)

                RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
                RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red




                Mid(TZZ, y, 12) = "123456789012"
                X = y
            End If

        Next X

        RichTextBox1.Select(0, 0)
```